# How does $ 0 \le a \lt p^\alpha $ in Theorem 5.30 of Introduction to Analytic Number Theory (Apostol)?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, modular-arithmetic

Theorem 5.30 from Introduction to Analytic Number Theory (Apostol) has a long proof. I am unable to understand one specific step in it.

First it assumes that $ \alpha \ge 2 $ and $ r $ is a solution of the congruence $$ f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{\alpha - 1}} $$ where $ r $ lies in the interval $ 0 \le r < p^{\alpha - 1}$.

In one of the steps of the proof it defines a variable $ a $ as $$ a = r + qp^{\alpha - 1} $$ and shows that $ a $ satisfies $ f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^\alpha} $ if and only if $ q $ satisfies the congruence $ qf'(r) + k \equiv 0 \pmod{p} $. The variable $ q $ was described to be "an integer to be specified presently".

Here is the step I am unable to understand:

> If $ f'(r) \equiv 0 \pmod{p} $ this congruence ($qf'(r) + k \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$) has a unique solution $ q $ mod $ p $, and if we choose $ q $ in the interval $ 0 \le q \lt p $ then the number $ a $ given by (22) will satisfy (20) and will lie in the interval $ 0 \le a < p^\alpha $.

How will $ a $ lie in the interval $ 0 \le a < p^\alpha $?

The equation (22) just refers to $ a = r + qp^{\alpha - 1} $.

Only two constraints have been specified $ 0 \le r < p^{\alpha - 1} $ and $ 0 \le a \lt p^\alpha $. If I combine these two inequalities, I get

$$
a = r + qp^{\alpha - 1} \lt p^{\alpha - 1} + p \cdot p^{\alpha - 1} = p^{\alpha - 1} + p^\alpha.
$$

I don't get $ 0 \le a < p^\alpha $. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Use the $\le$ instead of the $<$ to get sharper bounds (thanks to the fact that we are using integers, there is an actual gap between the two). You get

$$ a= r +qp^{\alpha-1} \le (p^{\alpha-1} -1 )+ (p-1) p^{\alpha-1} = (p^{\alpha-1} -1) + (p^{\alpha} - p^{\alpha-1}) = p^{\alpha} -1 < p^{\alpha} $$